# CSS element to wrap data after X number of results

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Is there a way in CSS to wrap text after X number of results in my ng-repeat?

See code below.

CSS:

```
.orders-container {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="orders-container">
    <ul>
        <span class="order-title">Orders</span>
            <li ng-repeat="num in nums track by $index">
                <span class="part-title">{{ nums }}</span>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

UI display current - this list could easily be 10 or 20 times this long. So I'd like to wrap into a new column after so many results.

```
Orders
6432508
6432512
6432513
6432511
6432509
```

UI display future:

```
Orders
6432508  6432515
6432512  6432516
6432513  6432517
6432511  6432518
6432509  6432519
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) modal.

```css
.orders-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.orders-container ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 120px;
  background: black;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="orders-container">
  <span class="order-title">Orders</span>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432508</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432509</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432510</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432511</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432512</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="orders-container">
  <span class="order-title">Orders</span>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432508</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432509</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432510</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432511</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432512</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432513</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432514</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432515</span></li>
    <li><span class="part-title">6432516</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But after how many rows does it decide to wrap? Is there a way to specify like after 25 start a new column?

Comment: @Andrew you can increase  or decrease `max-height` to adjust more or less items in a single column.